# Manually set value object's properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular9

I am trying to manually set a value object's properties **if the data for it does not exist from the service call.**

The data comes from a service call (it works, because I get data back). The object looks from the service call looks like this:

```js
export class AllHouseData {
    dataList: HouseResponse[];
    numberOfHouses: number;
}
```

The value object for the HouseResponse object looks like this:

```js
export class HouseResponse {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    settings: HouseSettings[];
}
```

The value object for the HouseSettings object looks like this:

```js
export class HouseSettings {
    id: number;
    houseCode: string
    parking: any;
}
```

Here is the code where I am trying to assign the object's properties:

```js
export class HouseComponent implements OnInit {
    houseData: AllHouseData;

    callHouseService(houseList) {
        this.houseService.getHouseData(houseList).subscribe((data) => {
            this.houseData = data;
            if (data === null) {
                this.houseData.dataList = [
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "",
                        settings: [{ id: number, houseCode: "", parking: false }],
                    },
                ];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Typescript gives me no errors when trying to set the data manually. However, in the console of the browser, I get the following error: *ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'dataList')*.

My question is, what is the correct way to go about setting this object manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your getHouseData call is returning null and you have no check for this.

If you need this.houseData to always have a value I would recommend a constructor with default values.

```
export class HouseSettings {
  constructor(public id = 0, houseCode = '', parking = false) {}
}
export class HouseResponse {
  constructor(public id = 0, name = '', public settings = [new HouseSettings()]) {}
}

export class AllHouseData {
  constructor(public dataList = [new HouseResponse()], public numberOfHouses = 0) {}
}
```

then in your subscription you could simply use:

```
data => this.houseData = data ?? new AllHouseData()
```

Comment: where should I create the default constructors at? @soylentthegreen

Comment: the example I gave has default constructors.